# Python cgi.fieldstorage ignoring values after semicolon

Tags: python, escaping, cgi

I am sending a string through cgi.fieldstorage in python.
It isn't accepting the characters after the ';'

I am sending a string

```
str = "Hello; World"

It only accepts "Hello" and ignores the " World"
```

tried cgi.escape(str) and re.escape(str)

Any idea on how to escape the semicolon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use backslash "\" ?, str = "Hello\; World"

Comment: Yes i did. It just returns "Hello\".

Comment: What is the python version you are using? It's know bug and should be fixed.

http://bugs.python.org/issue1540529

Comment: python 2.7.6, i'm afraid.